# Como unir vários select count(*) no mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada `tb.teste` que possui 4 colunas: `status`, `categoria`, `mês`e `tier.`

E em cada coluna, aceita os seguintes valores:

```
status (novo, usado, pós venda)
categoria (venda, não venda, aberto)
mês (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
tier (T1, T2, T3, Outro)
```

Eu quero retornar os resultados de uma contagem da seguinte consulta:

```
mês = '1', tier = 'T1', status = 'novo' e categoria = 'venda'
```

fiz assim:

```sql
select count(*) as contagem_1 from tb_teste
where mes = 1 and status = 'novo' and categoria = 'venda' and tier = 'T1';
```

Até ai tudo certo... o select me retornou a contagem quando todos os campos atendem a essas condições...

Mas eu queria retornar em uma tabela dos diferentes resultados de todas as combinações possíveis...

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Basta efetuar o agrupamento nas quatro colunas e agregar com a função desejada.

```sql
SELECT
    status,
    categoria,
    mes,
    tier,
    COUNT(1) as total
FROM tb_teste
GROUP BY status, categoria, mes, tier
```

Assim será retornado todas as combinações possíveis entre as colunas junto com a coluna com a quantidade de registros.